# VBA - GET statuses/home_timeline error

Tags: vba, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json

Whenever I try to use any additional parameters like:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=10

This gives me the following error:

`2 0 7316141533e2c2eb020dad48d3fb1d955b42c197 {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}`

I don't get any errors when I don't use any additional parameters.

Also How can I limit the amount of information I receive from the home_timeline? I only need "created_at", "id", "text", "source", "name" and "screen_name" keys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **What language are you using?**

Comment: Better if you show the code you're using, otherwise we're just guessing what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jimbo/Tim for taking the time to edit my question.
This is the response I just got from a twitter employee @c_r_w Craig Wright 
Unfortunately, there is no way to specify which data to return with the current API